# Date input too wide in chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im using Bootstrap and date inputs. With firefox as the screen gets narrower the date input resize. However with Chrome they dont resize and become too wide.

[image]

http://www.bootply.com/rgbzpIazj9

```
 <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-default-new">
                                    <label>Start</label> 
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-default-grey-new" placeholder="Ideal start date">
                                    </div>
                                </div>    
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group form-group-default-new">
                                    <label>Duration</label> 
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-default-grey-new" placeholder="Duration">
                                    </div>    
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the width, as the code sample below:

```
.input-group .form-control {
   width: 74%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine on my chrome browser. You have to use also other classes like .lg, .md, and .xs so that so that when browser window comes in specific width it shows that appearance according to bootstrap grid system.